# Is there a way to include Multiple Children inside a Container?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

This is full code:

```dart
class Application extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
       body: new Container(
         color: Color(0xff258DED),
         height: 400.0,
         alignment: Alignment.center,
         child: new Container(
           height: 200.0,
           width: 200.0,
           decoration: new BoxDecoration(
             image: DecorationImage(
                 image: new AssetImage('assets/logo.png'),
             fit: BoxFit.fill
             ),
             shape: BoxShape.circle
           ),
         ),
         child: new Container(
          child: new Text('Welcome to Prime Message',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Aleo',
                fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 25.0,
                color: Colors.white
            ),
          ),
         ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to add a `Container` on top and then added two children inside it. First child works fine, but second child giving me error like "the argument for the named parameter 'child' was already specified".

Comment: You have to use  mutichild widget like Column , Row , Stack.... It deepends on how you want to lay your widgets

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you try to put more than one child in a container, you want to look as `Row()` or `Column()` class for linear ones. `Stack()` is used if you want to have floating children on top of each other.

Eg:

```
class Application extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new MaterialApp(
            home: new Scaffold(
                body: new Container(
                    color: Color(0xff258DED),
                    height: 400.0,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: new Column(
                        children: [
                            new Container(
                                height: 200.0,
                                width: 200.0,
                                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                    image: DecorationImage(
                                        image: new AssetImage('assets/logo.png'),
                                        fit: BoxFit.fill
                                    ),
                                    shape: BoxShape.circle
                                ),
                            ),
                            new Container(
                                child: new Text('Welcome to Prime Message',
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontFamily: 'Aleo',
                                        fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        fontSize: 25.0,
                                        color: Colors.white
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
                        ],
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ill look into it

Answer (score 4):

`Container` is a [Single-child layout widget](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets/layout#Single-child%20layout%20widgets). But it can have multiple children by using a [Multi-child layout widget](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets/layout#Multi-child%20layout%20widgets) as its child.

Answer (score 3):

In the container can be only child.
You have to use Column widget and add Container widgets as children if you want them position vertically.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        body: new Container(
          color: Color(0xff258DED),
          height: 400.0,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 200.0,
                width: 200.0,
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: new AssetImage('assets/logo.png'),
                        fit: BoxFit.fill
                    ),
                    shape: BoxShape.circle
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child:Text('Welcome to Prime Message',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Aleo',
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 25.0,
                      color: Colors.white
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

tip #1 You don't have to use 'new' word to create object.
tip #2 Read about Column, Row and Stack on flutter.dev

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code:-

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext mContext) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          color: Color(0xff258DED),
          height: 400.0,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 200.0,
                width: 200.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage('assets/logo.png'),
                        fit: BoxFit.fill
                    ),
                    shape: BoxShape.circle
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Text('Welcome to Prime Message',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Aleo',
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 25.0,
                      color: Colors.white
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```