# Adding two containers, one for text, the others one for viewgrid

Tags: flutter

I really tried from yesterday, I'm really new to flutter so I'm trying to grasp how flutter widgets are working together. I want to have two containers; one for like introduction with text, second for viewgrid.

What I did so far:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: 
              Container(
alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        height: 200,
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(  
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(40.0),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(40.0)
            ) ,
          gradient: LinearGradient(  
            begin: Alignment.topRight,
            end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            colors: [
              Color(0xFF3383CD),
              Color(0xFF11249F)
            ]
          )
        ),

child: Column(children: <Widget>[

    Text('Deliver features faster', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    ),
    Text('Craft beautiful UIs', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    ),

],


),

      ),
      Container (  

      )

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It gave me this message : `Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.` Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to include Multiple Children inside a Container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57553821/is-there-a-way-to-include-multiple-children-inside-a-container)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Container can have only 1 child, so the problem you are having is that you have add 2 Widgets to its children, Try adding the last container inside the Column.

Also you can have 2 container in the Column using this code:

```
Container(
child: Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      // For text
    ),
    Container(
      // For Viewgrid
    )
  ]
)
```

)

Comment: how can i set the height for each container ?

Comment: @Anabe just add "height" attribute

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect. That last `Container` is not inside of `Column` widget.

Answer (score 0):

The `body` property of a `Scaffold` accepts a single widget. You probably search for a single widget that can accept multiple children, this way you'd be able to lay out your two containers. [You have many Multi-child layout widgets](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/layout#Multi-child%20layout%20widgets), the most common are Column, which lets you lay out your widgets vertically, and Row, which lets you lay out your widgets horizontally. I recommend reading [Layouts in Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout) to better understand layout in general.